# DELETE with to_date sub-query in Oracle DBMS

Tags: mysql

Am trying to delete some old records out of a small employee database (with the older records in archive).

The relevant tables of the DB have the following structure:

> **Employee** {EmployeeID, FamilyName, MiddleName, GivenName, Address, Suburb, State,
> ZipCode}
>
> **Expense** {ExpenseNo, ManagerID, EmployeeID, LodgementDate}

EmployeeID is the FK in the Expense relation. LodgementDate is in the format MM-DD-YYYY.

Writing the following just seems to delete all the records in the (test) DB, and not those older than (or even matching) the date:

```
DELETE FROM employee
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT *
    FROM employee, expense
    WHERE employee.employeeid= expense.employeeid
    AND lodgementdate = to_date('08-01-2007', 'MM-DD-YYYY'));
```

I know that there is a record that has that exact LodgementDate, however it still deletes all records (this is the test bed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove patient from the from clause of your exists.

```
DELETE FROM patient
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT *
    FROM account
    WHERE patient.patientid = account.patientid
    AND treatmentdate = to_date('01-JAN-07', 'DD-MON-YY'));
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I spend a lot more time on the ORM (web-dev) side of a DB than with the raw SQL, so the syntax does catch me occasionally.

Comment: +1 good answer.  FYI, though, the alternative `delete from patient where patientid in (select patient_id from account where treatmentdate=to_date('01-JAN-07', 'DD-MON-YY'))` _may_ be better in this case.  See [this discussion](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/oracle-tip-understand-the-difference-between-in-and-exists-in-subqueries/5297080).  Interesting when performance matters.